# Extending RAID-1 with two more disk (RAID-1 => RAID 1+0)

Tags: raid, disk

I have a Ubuntu 12.10 installation with (software) RAID-1 - only for data (root-system and swap are on another drive). Now I would like to add two more drives to the existing RAID 1 (basically to have RAID 1+0).

I'm pretty clueless on how to do it: how to configure/convert RAID 1 to RAID 1+0?

Also, is it possible to perform this without data loss (I suppose not)?

Comment: What look your install now? Wich size, your disks? Please post `df -PhlT`, `cat /proc/partitions` and `cat /proc/mdstat` outputs!

Comment: And yes, of course! If you have 2 empty disk, you could surely do this without data loss, but this could take some time and attention... Care!

Comment: It's a duplicate, there is already an answer: [Convert RAID 1 to RAID 10 in mdadm](http://superuser.com/questions/610538/convert-raid-1-to-raid-10-in-mdadm)

Answer (score 0):

#### The Royal way:

Yes, of course, your could move all your install without loosing any data!!!

If all your disk has same size, there is a very quiet way:

- build a new *degraded* Raid-10 array with 2 of 4 disks
- copy all your installation on this new array (may be partitionned by using LVM)
- correct /etc for ensuring boot (there are some stuff to do)
- change the boot sector only on new disk! (At this time, your installation is not modified at all!!!)
- Reboot your pc and change boot order to boot on new *degraded* Raid-10
- If everything work you could now

  - mount old raid 1 and check/verify your copy (diff)
  - destroy your raid 1
  - hot add your two old disks to your new raid 10.

<s>If you answer to my first comments, I will post detailled commands to do this...</s>

... maybe, later.

Take a look at: [Convert RAID 1 to RAID 10 in mdadm](https://superuser.com/a/726063/178656)